# Private Setter in Objective-C, accessing from Swift 3.2+

Tags: swift, private-members

Here is a situation we saw in moving from Xcode 8 to 9 (Swift 3.1->Swift 3.2/4). Its a common case of having a public header that has read-only properties and private headers with read/write definitions as well as Swift code (unit tests in this case, but could simply be a mixed ObjC/Swift project) that needs to access the setters. I thought I'd share how we resolved this.

Main Class:

**Objective-C Header**

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    @property (nonnull, nonatomic, readonly) SomeOtherClass* var;
}
@end
```

Then we have a private header:

**Objective-C Header**

```
@interface SomeClass (Testing) {
    @property (nonnull, nonatomic, readwrite) SomeOtherClass* var;
}
@end
```

Then in a Bridging header we include both the original header and the private header. Using Xcode 8 (Swift 3.1), this worked fine. In Xcode 9 (Swift 3.2/4), we're getting an error that the property is read-only.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for us:

Change the private testing header to use:

```
@protocol SomeClassTesting <NSObject>
    @property (nonnull, nonatomic, readwrite) SomeOtherClass* var;
@end

@interface SomeClass (Testing) <SomeClassTesting>
@end
```